# Training keeps stopping. Tuple error. (Tensorflow Object_detection API)

Tags: python, tensorflow, training-data, object-detection-api

I am using tensorflow's object detection API, whenever I execute training it stops after a few iterations. Initially I had my images in jpg format from which I created XML files the converted to CSV, however, people mentioned that the cause of error could be in using jpg and not jpeg (although others have gotten it to work in jpg format). I then converted my images to jpeg and carried out the rest of the steps, then comes training and the same issue arises. I've been stuck on this issue for so long to no avail and there doesn't seem to be many working solutions out there. If anyone has an idea to solve this, I would be extremely grateful. Code below

```
Instructions for updating:
Please switch to tf.train.get_or_create_global_step
WARNING:root:Variable [Conv/biases/Momentum] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [Conv/weights/Momentum] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [FirstStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/biases/Momentum] is not available in checkpoint
WARNING:root:Variable [FirstStageBoxPredictor/BoxEncodingPredictor/weights/Momentum] is not available in checkpoint
```

....

```
    INFO:tensorflow:global step 1: loss = 1.6760 (13.660 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:global step 1: loss = 1.6760 (13.660 sec/step)
INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/writer/writer.py:386: UserWarning: Attempting to use a closed FileWriter. The operation will be a noop unless the FileWriter is explicitly reopened.
  warnings.warn("Attempting to use a closed FileWriter. "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 185, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 324, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "train.py", line 181, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 416, in train
    saver=saver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 785, in train
    ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 832, in stop
    ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 257, in _run
    enqueue_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1257, in _single_operation_run
    self._call_tf_sessionrun(None, {}, [], target_list, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Shape mismatch in tuple component 18. Expected [1,?,?,3], got [1,1,314,384,3]
     [[{{node batch/padding_fifo_queue_enqueue}}]]
```

**Train.py**

```
    """Training executable for detection models.

This executable is used to train DetectionModels. There are two ways of
configuring the training job:

1) A single pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig configuration file
can be specified by --pipeline_config_path.

Example usage:
    ./train \
        --logtostderr \
        --train_dir=path/to/train_dir \
        --pipeline_config_path=pipeline_config.pbtxt

2) Three configuration files can be provided: a model_pb2.DetectionModel
configuration file to define what type of DetectionModel is being trained, an
input_reader_pb2.InputReader file to specify what training data will be used and
a train_pb2.TrainConfig file to configure training parameters.

Example usage:
    ./train \
        --logtostderr \
        --train_dir=path/to/train_dir \
        --model_config_path=model_config.pbtxt \
        --train_config_path=train_config.pbtxt \
        --input_config_path=train_input_config.pbtxt
"""
#changed  object_detection.builders/legacy/utils to builders...

import functools
import json
import os
import tensorflow as tf

from builders import dataset_builder
from builders import graph_rewriter_builder
from builders import model_builder
from legacy import trainer
from utils import config_util

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

flags = tf.app.flags
flags.DEFINE_string('master', '', 'Name of the TensorFlow master to use.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('task', 0, 'task id')
flags.DEFINE_integer('num_clones', 1, 'Number of clones to deploy per worker.')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('clone_on_cpu', False,
                     'Force clones to be deployed on CPU.  Note that even if '
                     'set to False (allowing ops to run on gpu), some ops may '
                     'still be run on the CPU if they have no GPU kernel.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('worker_replicas', 1, 'Number of worker+trainer '
                     'replicas.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('ps_tasks', 0,
                     'Number of parameter server tasks. If None, does not use '
                     'a parameter server.')
flags.DEFINE_string('train_dir', '',
                    'Directory to save the checkpoints and training summaries.')

flags.DEFINE_string('pipeline_config_path', '',
                    'Path to a pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig config '
                    'file. If provided, other configs are ignored')

flags.DEFINE_string('train_config_path', '',
                    'Path to a train_pb2.TrainConfig config file.')
flags.DEFINE_string('input_config_path', '',
                    'Path to an input_reader_pb2.InputReader config file.')
flags.DEFINE_string('model_config_path', '',
                    'Path to a model_pb2.DetectionModel config file.')

FLAGS = flags.FLAGS


@tf.contrib.framework.deprecated(None, 'Use object_detection/model_main.py.')
def main(_):

  assert FLAGS.train_dir, '`train_dir` is missing.'
  if FLAGS.task == 0: tf.gfile.MakeDirs(FLAGS.train_dir)
  if FLAGS.pipeline_config_path:
    configs = config_util.get_configs_from_pipeline_file(
        FLAGS.pipeline_config_path)
    if FLAGS.task == 0:
      tf.gfile.Copy(FLAGS.pipeline_config_path,
                    os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir, 'pipeline.config'),
                    overwrite=True)
  else:
    configs = config_util.get_configs_from_multiple_files(
        model_config_path=FLAGS.model_config_path,
        train_config_path=FLAGS.train_config_path,
        train_input_config_path=FLAGS.input_config_path)
    if FLAGS.task == 0:
      for name, config in [('model.config', FLAGS.model_config_path),
                           ('train.config', FLAGS.train_config_path),
                           ('input.config', FLAGS.input_config_path)]:
        tf.gfile.Copy(config, os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir, name),
                      overwrite=True)

  model_config = configs['model']
  train_config = configs['train_config']
  input_config = configs['train_input_config']

  model_fn = functools.partial(
      model_builder.build,
      model_config=model_config,
      is_training=True)

  def get_next(config):
    return dataset_builder.make_initializable_iterator(
        dataset_builder.build(config)).get_next()

  create_input_dict_fn = functools.partial(get_next, input_config)

  env = json.loads(os.environ.get('TF_CONFIG', '{}'))
  cluster_data = env.get('cluster', None)
  cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec(cluster_data) if cluster_data else None
  task_data = env.get('task', None) or {'type': 'master', 'index': 0}
  task_info = type('TaskSpec', (object,), task_data)

  # Parameters for a single worker.
  ps_tasks = 0
  worker_replicas = 1
  worker_job_name = 'lonely_worker'
  task = 0
  is_chief = True
  master = ''

  if cluster_data and 'worker' in cluster_data:
    # Number of total worker replicas include "worker"s and the "master".
    worker_replicas = len(cluster_data['worker']) + 1
  if cluster_data and 'ps' in cluster_data:
    ps_tasks = len(cluster_data['ps'])

  if worker_replicas > 1 and ps_tasks < 1:
    raise ValueError('At least 1 ps task is needed for distributed training.')

  if worker_replicas >= 1 and ps_tasks > 0:
    # Set up distributed training.
    server = tf.train.Server(tf.train.ClusterSpec(cluster), protocol='grpc',
                             job_name=task_info.type,
                             task_index=task_info.index)
    if task_info.type == 'ps':
      server.join()
      return

    worker_job_name = '%s/task:%d' % (task_info.type, task_info.index)
    task = task_info.index
    is_chief = (task_info.type == 'master')
    master = server.target

  graph_rewriter_fn = None
  if 'graph_rewriter_config' in configs:
    graph_rewriter_fn = graph_rewriter_builder.build(
        configs['graph_rewriter_config'], is_training=True)

  trainer.train(
      create_input_dict_fn,
      model_fn,
      train_config,
      master,
      task,
      FLAGS.num_clones,
      worker_replicas,
      FLAGS.clone_on_cpu,
      ps_tasks,
      worker_job_name,
      is_chief,
      FLAGS.train_dir,
      graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  tf.app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

This line should give you an hint: `Expected [1,?,?,3], got [1,1,314,384,3]`
Tensorflow uses 4D Tensors as the image input of a model, that's why a Tensor of size `[1,?,?,3]` is expected. However, you provide a 5D Tensor. I guess, that there is one `tf.expand_dims()` to much in your code somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I had been trying to solve the issue for quite sometime, there was a weird error that some images would show the error stated above and some wouldn't. For some reason Tensorflow's Object Detection API can't train properly when the dataset consists of JPG images(works with JPEG), something to do when generating TFrecords. Initially my dataset consisted of JPG images, I tried to solve the issue without trying to relabel my dataset by editing the csv files but had no success. I re-did the entire process with JPEG and it works now!! Learnt a lot while trying to fix it!

Comment: ARGH, I'm facing the same issue again! It seemed as though it was resolved, once I expanded my dataset (all in JPEG) the issue came back with a vengeance. I tried editing the eval_util.py file in the object_detection directory. However, it doesn't seem to make a difference. Even when I delete eval_util.py, it doesn't seem to make a difference. Hence, even editing the tensor size doesn't affect the outcome. I don't know what's wrong, I hardly see other people facing this problem.

Comment: As the error traceback ```"train.py", line 185, in <module> tf.app.run()``` indicates, your error occurs in the train.py file. You should provide this code to help you.

Comment: I've attached the entire code from train.py. To be honest, I don't see how the train.py could have an error as I hadn't changed any part of it, it's exactly the same as the source. Also, the error does not occur at every training step. Btw, I'm really grateful for your constant feedback.

Comment: Solved the issue! There were no issues with the code, I hadn't checked the CSV files to see if any entries had height and width stored as 0. Found out that there were and after removing them, the error did not reappear! Thanks for the constant feedback! Now my mind can be at peace.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue, check your train and test CSV files to see if there are any entries with Width and Height as 0. This usually happens if the image is of different format to its extension. Solve the issue by either removing those images or convert them to proper format using -

```
img = cv2.imread(test_full_path)
cv2.imwrite(test_full_path, img, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 100])
```